# Closing mediaRecorder webcam when component unmounts using React useEffect

Tags: reactjs, web-mediarecorder

Why is it that this works: calling `unregister()` from a button, but it does not work via React useEffect callback.

Does not work:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      console.log("navigating from recorder");
      stopRecording();
      unregister();
    };
  }, []);
```

Works:
Calling `unregister()` from clicking a button in the component.

Wanted result: The browser should no longer display that recording is being done.

Sandbox illustrating the problem:
https://codesandbox.io/s/mediarecorder-react-navigation-vwmo2

Try opening the Sandbox, go to recorder, allow recording in the browser, and then navigating to home, the browser will still say (in the browser tab) that recording is being done.

Comment: I think both `stopRecording` and `unregister` should be in the dependency array. I added them though and didn't see any change in behavior of the UI. What is supposed to happen when the recorder is unregistered?

Comment: `unregister` should stop the tracks of the stream which should result in the browser no longer report that devices are being used. Here's the code for ´unregister´: https://github.com/haflinger/react-hook-recorder/blob/a3cb0c8317be49b80a74a58677bb22f1a058305e/src/useRecorder.ts#L97

Comment: Hey @jmn did you ever get this figured out? I'm having the same issue.